# when i want to update in this code i have 404 error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

**BLADE FILE**

```
{!!  Form::model($article,['method'=>'patch','url'=>['article/update',$article->id]]) !!}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
 public function update(Request $request,$id)
    {

        $article=Article::find($id);
        $article->update($request->all());
        return redirect('article');
    }
```

**WEB.PHP**

```
Route::resource('article','articleController');
```

Comment: when i press sumbit button shows 404 error and article/update/{id not found}

Comment: i think the update function not found in cotroller

Answer (score 0):

Change method to `put` and url to `article`

see this section https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers

`{!!  Form::model($article,['method'=>'put','url'=>['article', $article->id]]) !!}`

Answer (score 0):

To do so, use

```
{!!  Form::model($article,['route'=>['article.update',$article->id]]) !!}
```